# XML download from a url

Tags: python, xml, urllib2

I have written a code to download XML file from a website and store into database. But before download, I should parse the user credentials to the website. The code is working properly but I am unable to find the XML downloaded path. can you help me on this. users are loaded from MySQL database.
url='https://emergencyprocedures.pjm.com/

```
for user in users:
    authentication_handle=urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
    authentication_handle.add_password(None,url,user[0],user[1])

    handler=urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(authentication_handle)

    url_opener=urllib2.build_opener(handler)
    file_details=url_opener.open(url)
    tree=ET.parse(XMLfile)
    root=tree.getroot()
```

for tree I should parse XML file path. I am unable to find the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try to *read* the XML first, and then pass the result to elementtree :

```
.....
file_details = url_opener.open(url).read()
root = ET.fromstring(file_details)
```

And if somehow the *tree* is needed as well :

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The XML will be different to each user. So we should login first before downloading the XML.